# Percorrer um array bash script

Tags: linux, bash

Alguém pode me dar um exemplo de um if e case percorrendo um array em bash script? eu só estou achando exemplo com for que é pra listar os itens..
estou tentando assim porem não da certo
ex:

```
v1=("sim" "s" "y" "yes" "")
v2=("não" "no" "nao")

read -p "Digite sua opção [S] [n]" RESP

case $RESP in
$V1)
echo "Opção sim"
;;
$V2)
echo "Opção não"
;;
*)
echo "Não conheço"
;;
esca
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você não precisa de malabarismos com *arrays*, a sintaxe de `case/esac` permite que você teste uma lista de valores separados por `|`, veja só:

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Digite sua opção [S/N]: " RESP

case ${RESP,,} in

    "sim"|"s"|"y"|"yes"|"")
        echo "Opção sim"
    ;;

    "não"|"n"|"nao"|"no")
        echo "Opção não"
    ;;

    *)
        echo "Não conheço"
    ;;

esac
```

Porém, se o uso das *arrays* for um pré-requisito obrigatório, existe uma solução usando os condicionais `if/elif/else/fi` com o operador `=~`, que verifica se um valor específico está contido dentro de uma *array*:

```
#!/bin/bash

v1=("sim" "s" "y" "yes" "")
v2=("não" "no" "nao" "n")

read -p "Digite sua opção [S/N]: " RESP

if [[ "${v1[@]}" =~ "${RESP,,}" ]]; then
    echo "Opção sim"
elif [[ "${v2[@]}" =~ "${RESP,,}" ]]; then
    echo "Opção não"
else
    echo "Não conheço"
fi
```

Repare que `${RESP,,}` faz com que todas as letras contidas na variável `$RESP` sejam lidas em letras mínúsculas (*lowercase*), tornando indiferente se o que foi digitato pelo usuário foi em caixa baixa (*lowercase*) ou em caixa alta (*uppercase*).

Comment: Cara não poderia ter uma resposta mais completa que a sua, principalmente a dica do ${RESP,,} que eu não sabia haha, muito obrigado!!!